What does this use of でいい mean?
Context: A Japanese character is watching a video featuring Americans and is in awe at the behavior of people from the what she refers to as the "Land of the Free". During this moment, she thinks.

人はこんなにも自由でいいんだ！

I've been trying to figure out the meaning behind this sentence's use of でいい, but no other explanation of the phrase really fits with the translation provided.
From what I have learned, the meaning of でいい is "fine with...", or is used to seek confirmation. But the context of the sentence and the provided translation through DeepL (I know that this is a cardinal sin in language learning to use AI translation, but I was just too stumped on this one), which was "People are so much freer." doesn't seem to align with any previously mentioned definition of でいい.
I've been able to translate it as (These) people are fine with this much freedom!, but it doesn't feel correct given the context. Again, no explanation I could find properly explains this. This use of でいい seems to act like an emphatic variation of だ. It doesn't align with any of the given definitions, but it certainly makes more sense in the context than what I've been told. What am I missing? Which use of でいい am I dealing with here? And how does the etymology allow for this usage?

How about "people should be this free!"

I'm not good at grammatical explanation, so just some ideas...

The sentence can be rephrased as "人はこんなにも自由になっても良いのだ！"
"(I'm surprised that) people can be so free!" (meaning speaker thinks people can not be so free in her common practice)
The subject of "でいい" ("fine with...") here might be "Society" or "surrounding people", which was omitted. "(American) Society is fine with these free people".

These ideas ring some bells for you?
